# Time complexity of python function

Tags: python, time-complexity

I am trying to solve the time complexity of this function (I'm still new to solving complexity problems) and was wondering what the time complexity of this function would be:

```
def mystery(lis):
    n = len(lis)
    for index in range(n):
        x = 2*index % n
        lis[index],lis[x] = lis[x],lis[index]
    print(lis)
```

I believe the answer is O(n) but I am not 100% sure as the line: `x = 2*index % n` is making me wonder if it is maybe O(n log n).

Answer (score 0):

The operation to `*` two operands together is usually consider constant time in time complexity analysis. Same with `%`.

The fact that you have `n` as one of the operand doesn't make it `O(n)` because `n` is a single number. To make it `O(n)` you need to perform an operation `n` times.

Comment: So would this be complexity O(1) then? Or is it still O(n) because we are working with the index in range(n)?

Comment: It is O(n) because it is performing these operations:
```
x = 2*index % n
lis[index],lis[x] = lis[x],lis[index]
```
n times